# Работа функций range(max())

Tags: python, python-3.x

не совсем понимаю как работает данный код

```
n = 6
for x in range(max(n, 0)):
    print(n)
```

а именно функции `range(max(n,0))`

Comment: Выражение `max(n,0)` выбирает самое большое число из перечисленных и таким образом гарантирует, что оно никогда не будет меньше нуля, а `range` возвращает объект-итератор, который генерирует числа от 0 до указанного числа (не включая это самое число)

Comment: @andreymal а что значит ноль? с какого числа начать, не могу просто найти что значит второй параметр в функции max

Comment: Ещё раз: «выбирает самое большое число из перечисленных», ноль — это просто ещё одно число, с которым проводится сравнение

Comment: `max(3, 5)` выдаст 5, `max(4, 1)` выдаст 4 и так далее

Comment: `for x in range(max(n, 0))` - цикл, в котором `x` поочередно принимает значения диапазона чисел - от `0` (потому что счет начинается с нуля, а не потому, что ноль указан в параметре функции) до `n` (вернее, от нуля до найденного большего) . При `n <= 0` цикл не сработает. `print(x)` - так должно быть в теле цикла, иначе какой смысл выводить `n` раз число `n`?

Answer (score 1):

```py
for x in range(max(n, 0)):
```

Вообще это бессмысленная конструкция. Код `max(n, 0)` ограничивает нижнее значение этого выражения нулём, то есть при любом `n <= 0` выражение `max(n, 0)` будет равно `0`. При этом и `range(0)` и `range(n)` при `n <= 0` одинаково дадут итератор, который не выдаст ничего, цикл ни разу не сработает. Таким образом, это выражение бессмысленно (по крайней мере для целых `n`), можно точно так же оставить просто:

```py
for x in range(n):
```

И ничего не поменяется.